# Markdown not recognizing characters in URLs, redux: dollar sign

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks, url-encoding

I have two links which I am trying to use in an answer:

```
[10–4–5 (for Terminal facilities)][3]
[6–4–4 (for Enroute facilities)][4]
```

and two URLs which those links should point to:

```
 [3]: https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/foa_html/chap10_section_4.html#$paragraph10-4-5
 [4]: https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/foa_html/chap6_section_4.html#$paragraph6-4-4
```

You will note that both URLs are links to anchors within a page, and that both anchors include the characters `$` and `-`.

The first link works:

> [10–4–5 (for Terminal facilities)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/foa_html/chap10_section_4.html#$paragraph10-4-5)

The second does not:

> [6–4–4 (for Enroute facilities)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/foa_html/chap6_section_4.html#$paragraph6-4-4)

...or, well, it doesn't work [in my answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/88955/54557) (see [revisions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/88955/revisions)), despite working here in this question. The problem seems to be with the dollar sign—removing it from the URL causes Markdown to recognize it, while inserting it anywhere in the URL causes the recognition to instantly vanish. **Encoding `$` as `%24` allows Markdown to recognize the URL again.**

Note that all four of the "dash-like" symbols in the two anchors are simple hyphens, not en-dashes.

**Why does the URL recognition break only for the one URL, and not both of them? Why is the encoding necessary in my answer there, but not my question here?**

Comment: Might be something to do with how Aviation uses $ as its MathJax delimiter? (Meta SE does not have MathJax enabled). There appears to be a [7 year old request](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/384) to change the delimiter to \$ over there.